# Get value of selected row from table in one JSP to another JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to select a row from a table which has multiple row and display the values of the selected row in another JSP.

But whichever row I select, I only get the values of the 1st row. The table data which is selected from 1st JSP is populated from `.js` file.

Here is a snippet of code from my 1st JSP:

```
<div>
 <form class="form-inline" name = "select_req" action="/Main.do" method = post>
     <table class="table" id = "searchresult">
         <tr>
             <th>From</th>
             <th>To</th>
             <th>Airline</th>
             <th>Fare</th>
             <th>Action</th>
         </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="flight in flights | filter:query">
             <td><input value = "{{flight.from}}" name = "from"></td>
             <td><input value = "{{flight.to}}" name = "to"></td>
             <td><input value = "{{flight.airline}}" name = "airline"></td>
             <td><input value = "{{flight.fare}}" name = "fare"></td>
             <td><input type="submit" value="Select" name = "select_req" class="btn btn-success"/></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
     <input type="hidden"/>
 </form>
</div>
```

This is the servlet code which sends it to another JSP:

```java
 @Override
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     String from = request.getParameter("from");        
     String to = request.getParameter("to");        
     String airline = request.getParameter("airline");      
     String fare = request.getParameter("fare");
     HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 
     session.setAttribute("from", from);
     session.setAttribute("to", to);
     session.setAttribute("airline", airline);
     session.setAttribute("fare", fare);

     request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/Payment.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Finally the JSP were the selected row from the table needs to be displayed:

```
<table class = "table">
             <tr>
                 <th>From</th>
                 <th>To</th>
                <th>Airline</th>

                <th>Fare</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%= session.getAttribute("from") %></td>
                <td><%= session.getAttribute("to") %></td>
                <td><%= session.getAttribute("airline") %></td>
                <td>$<%= session.getAttribute("fare")  %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The form element contains all the input element of all table rows. When you submit the form it will send the value of all these input elements to the server.

Now on the server all parameters are multivalued. If you call `ServletRequest.getParameter(String)` it will return the first value - which corresponds to the input in your first table row.

Check this by calling `request.getParameterValues("from")` - it should return an array whose length equals the number of rows in your table, containing all inputs of the first table column.

What you probably want is to send only the values of the row which contains the pressed button. Either do this using Javascript or wrap each `<tr>` in an own `<form>` element.

Comment: how do i send selected row only using Javascript or wrap each <tr> in an own <form> element.